# ¿Cómo girar una tabla nombre margen izquierda con knitr y xtable?

Tags: r, latex

Estoy intentando obtener un pdf con los resultados del comando table aplicado a dos vectores.

Para ello utilizo knitr y el paquete xtable, aunque otras soluciones y consejos son bienvenidos, como por ejemplo con Kable.

Como ejemplo podemos crear la tabla a partir de estos datos.

> table(c(2,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,NA),c(1,5,2,2,2,2,7,7,NA,NA))

Y me gustaría obtener algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis ver el título del margin izquierdo, var1 está rotado 90º.

¿Cómo puedo conseguir ese resultado o algo parecido?

He probado varios métodos, como muestro en el código adjunto, incluido en un archivo Rnw.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

<<r table, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(xtable)
var1 <- c(2,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,NA)
var2 <- c(1,5,2,2,2,2,7,7,NA,NA)

print(xtable(table(var1,var2)))

print.xtableFtable(xtableFtable(ftable(var1,var2), 
       method = "row.compact"))

print.xtableFtable(xtableFtable(ftable(var1,var2), 
       method = "row.compact"), rotate.rownames = TRUE)

print.xtable(xtable(table(var1,var2)), include.rownames=T,include.colnames=T)

@

\end{document}
```

Y el resultado obtenido se muestra en las siguientes tres tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como podéis comprobar no se parece a lo que yo busco, no consigo girar sólo var1.

Comment: Hello.. this is the spanish version of SO.. if you are a spanish speaker, please translate your question. if spanish if not your language, please then use SO in english to ask it.

Comment: Perdonad el error, es que suelo escribir en la versión inglesa porque tiene más participantes pero por error entré en la española, pero ya que estamos la he traducido.

Comment: Ya lo tenéis en lengua cervantina, espero vuestras respuestas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra solución, básicamente escribiendo una función de `print` en latex, para cualquier tabla:

```
latex_print_table <- function(tbl) {

    df_tbl <- as.data.frame(tbl)
    vnames <- names(df_tbl)[1:2]
    d <- dim(tbl)
    l1 <- unique(df_tbl[,1])
    l2 <- unique(df_tbl[,2])
    latex <- c('\\begin{table}[ht]',
               paste0('   \\begin{tabular}{c c | ', paste(rep('c', d[2]),collapse=" "),'}'),
               paste0('   & & \\multicolumn{', d[2], '}{c}{', vnames[2], '}\\\\'),
               paste0('   & &', paste0(l2, collapse= ' &'), ' \\\\'),
               '   \\hline')

    for (i in 1:d[1]) {
        row <- df_tbl[df_tbl[,1]==as.character(l1[i]), 3]
        if (i == 1) {
            latex <- c(latex, 
                       paste0('   \\multirow{', d[1],'}{*}{\\rotatebox{90}{', vnames[1], '}} & ',
                              as.character(l1[i]), " & ",
                              paste0(row, collapse=" & "), '\\\\'))
        } else {
            latex <- c(latex, '   & ',
                       as.character(l1[i]), " & ",
                       paste0(row, collapse=" & "), '\\\\')
        }
    } 
    latex <- c(latex, 
               '   \\hline',
               '   \\end{tabular}',
               '\\end{table}')

    cat(latex, collapse="\n")
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
var1 <- c(2,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,NA,9,1)
var2 <- c(1,5,2,2,2,2,7,7,NA,NA,9,9)

tbl <- table(var1, var2)
latex_print_table(tbl)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Menudo nivel, gracias.
Ahora mismo no lo necesito pero me lo guardo.

Answer (score 2):

Usa este código, esta es la solución que necesitas e incluyo colores por    si quieres que se vea mejor la tabla.

```
    \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{array,colortbl,xcolor,graphics}
    \usepackage{multicol,multirow}
    \begin{document}

      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\cline{3-9}
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{7}{c|}   {\cellcolor{blue!85}\color{white} Fertility and Natural Draimage} \\ \cline{3-9}
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & 64 & 32 & 16 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 0 \\ \hline
        \cellcolor{blue!85} & 512 & \cellcolor{green!55!black}S1 &     \cellcolor{green!55!black}S1 & \cellcolor{green!55!black}S1 &   \cellcolor{green!25!yellow}S2 & \cellcolor{green!25!yellow}S2 &    \cellcolor{orange!65}N1 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 \\ \cline{2-9}
        \cellcolor{blue!85} & 256 & \cellcolor{green!25!yellow}S2 & \cellcolor{green!25!yellow}S2 & \cellcolor{green!25!yellow}S2 & \cellcolor{green!25!yellow}S2 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{orange!65}N1 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 \\ \cline{2-9}
        \cellcolor{blue!85} & 128 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{orange!65}N1 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 \\ \cline{2-9}
        \cellcolor{blue!85} & 64 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{orange!65}N1 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 \\ \cline{2-9}
        \cellcolor{blue!85} & 32 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{yellow}S3 & \cellcolor{orange!65}N1 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 \\ \cline{2-9}
        \cellcolor{blue!85} & 16 & \cellcolor{orange!65}N1 & \cellcolor{orange!65}N1 & \cellcolor{orange!65}N1 & \cellcolor{orange!65}N1 & \cellcolor{orange!65}N1 & \cellcolor{orange!65}N1 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 \\ \cline{2-9}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{blue!85}\multirow{-7}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2.8cm}{\color{white}\centering\scriptsize Flooding, erosion,\\soil depth}}}} & 0 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 & \cellcolor{orange}N2 \\ \hline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Lo puedes compilar usando PdfLaTeX o XeLaTeX, en cualquiera de los dos casos el resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola y gracias por el comentario.  Pero lo que necesito no es crearlo directamente en latex sino con knitr, es decir de algún modo girarle el título a uno de los marginales de una tabla que ya ha sido generada por algún comando de R, ya que tengo muchas y según los datos de entrada pueden ir cambiando.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más parecido a lo que buscas que pude conseguir es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que se logra configurando directamente dos filas que haga las veces de cabecera de la tabla:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<r table, results='asis', echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(xtable)

var1 <- c(2,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,NA)
var2 <- c(1,5,2,2,2,2,7,7,NA,NA)

tbl <- table(var1, var2)
df_tbl <- as.data.frame(tbl)
vnames <- names(df_tbl)[1:2]
values <- as.character(unique(df_tbl[,2]))
d <- dim(tbl)

addtorow <- list()
addtorow$pos <- list(0, 0)
addtorow$command <- c(paste0("& \\multicolumn{", d[2], "}{c}{", vnames[2], "} \\\\\n"),
                      paste0(vnames[1], " & ", paste(values, collapse = " & "), "\\\\\n"))

print(xtable(tbl), add.to.row = addtorow, include.colnames = FALSE)

@
\end{document}
```

La idea es que `print.xtable()` agregue mediante el parámetro `add.to.row` unas filas dónde le digamos (`list(0, 0)`). De esta forma podremos escribir el comando latex directamente, que en este ejemplo se calcula dinámicamente de la propia tabla y quedaría así:

```
> addtorow$command
[1] "& \\multicolumn{4}{c}{var2} \\\\\n"
[2] "var1 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 7\\\\\n"
```

Se podría eventualmente girara `Var1` de la siguiente forma:

```
addtorow$command <- c(paste0("\\rotatebox{90}{", vnames[1], " } & \\multicolumn{", d[2], "}{c}{", vnames[2], "} \\\\\n"),
                      paste0( " & ", paste(values, collapse = " & "), "\\\\\n"))

print(xtable(tbl), add.to.row = addtorow, include.colnames = FALSE)
```

Encerramos el nombre de la variable en un comando latex `\\rotatebox{90}{..}`, no queda del todo elegante pero sin duda es más claro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pero quisiera girar var1

Comment: @skan, no es simple de resolver, lo más fácil es usar un `\\rotatebox{90}{..}`, lo más complejo, es reescribir completamente la función `print` para generar el código latex necesario, que además es complicado por que se necesitaría usar `multirow()` un paquete adicional de latex.